# Can the type of partial specialization be inferred?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, type-inference

I am designing a series of vectors to support some mathematical operations, part of the content is as follows

```
enum class precision
{
    high,
    medium,
    low,

    default_precision = high
};

template<typename T>
concept arithmetic = std::is_integral_v<T> || std::is_floating_point_v<T>;

using vector_size_type = std::size_t;
using matrix_size_type = std::size_t;
template<vector_size_type Size, arithmetic T, precision = precision::default_precision>
struct vector;

template<arithmetic T, precision P = precision::default_precision>
using vector1 = vector<1, T, P>;

template <arithmetic T, precision P>
struct vector<1, T, P>
{
    template <vector_size_type Size, arithmetic U>
    using acceptable_type = vector<Size, U, P>;

    using container_type = std::array<T, 1>;
    using value_type = typename container_type::value_type;
    using size_type = typename container_type::size_type;
    
    constexpr static size_type data_index = 0;
    constexpr static size_type data_size = 1;

    constexpr          vector() noexcept = default;

    constexpr explicit vector(value_type scalar) noexcept : data_({scalar}) {}
    
    template<arithmetic U>
    constexpr explicit vector(U scalar) noexcept(std::is_nothrow_convertible_v<U, value_type>) : data_({static_cast<value_type>(scalar)}) {}

    template<vector_size_type Size>
    requires (Size >= data_size)
    constexpr explicit vector(const acceptable_type<Size, value_type>& other) noexcept
        : data_({other[data_index]}) {}
    
    template <vector_size_type Size, typename U>
        requires (Size >= data_size)
    constexpr explicit vector(const acceptable_type<Size, U>& other) noexcept(std::is_nothrow_convertible_v<U, value_type>)
        : data_({static_cast<value_type>(other[data_index])}) {}

private:
    container_type data_;
};
```

```
//===========================================
// test
//==========================================
// OK
constexpr vector1<int> vec1{ 10 };
constexpr vector1<long> vec2{ -10 };

// missing parameter list for template alias vector1

// vector1 vec3{3.14};

// the template alias vector1 has too few parameters

// vector1<> vec4{1234};
```

what should I do to make vector1 have the function of type inference? Or can the type of partial specialization be inferred?

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/W7nG4nGnh

Comment: `vector vec3{3.14};` is possible with a [deduction guide](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction#User-defined_deduction_guides). Unsure about `vector vec3{3.14};`, you'll need to read into https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction#Deduction_for_alias_templates

Answer (score -1):

1. You need to end the `struct vector` with `};` instead of `}`
2. It is not necessary, but it is more common to use `size_t` instead of `size_type`, but they are still the same thing.
3. Why are you using `size_type`? Why not just use `int`.

Comment: Changing from `size_type` to `int` fixes all errors for me.

Comment: I get more errors: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/4qz5hvcWc

Comment: All my tests passed to make sure the code is correct, the only problem is that I want to be able to infer the type. :)